# Why am I not seeing .NET Framework 5 in the framework picker?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I downloaded and installed Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise today.  However when creating a new project, I am not seeing .NET 5.

According to my reading of the release [blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/released-today-visual-studio-2015-asp-net-4-6-asp-net-5-ef-7-previews), at least the beta of ASP.NET 5 and ASP.NET MVC 6 should have been included.

Am I missing something simple?

[image]

Comment: .Net framework versions is different from ASP.NET version. The framework version refers to the runtime version and from the link you provided it is 4.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version of the Microsoft .NET Framework that was released today (RTM) is .NET 4.6.  This is indeed in your screenshot.  Don't confused ASP.NET versions with .NET versions.  Your version selector in the screenshot is for the .NET Framework.

[Announcing .NET Framework 4.6](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2015/07/20/announcing-net-framework-4-6.aspx) *(this blog post was released today, 7/20/2015, on the release day of .NET 4.6)*

Answer (score 1):

No, 4.6 is the latest and greatest.  The closest you could get to a 5 is the DNX Core 5.0 runtime.  An early spin-off of the CoreCLR open source project, you can target it with a web project that you start from a "ASP.NET 5 Preview Templates" template.

It is not installed on your machine, as soon as you create the project it will automatically use Nuget to download the runtime.  Takes a while.  You'll get four of them, find them back in the `c:\users\yourname\.dnx` directory.  Work in progress, don't take a heavy dependency on it yet.